# Hierarchy sanpshot

Tags: history-tracking, role-hierarchy

I have a tricky situation. I have more than 350 sales people in my org and I have 4 levels in my hierarchy and hierarchy changes monthly. In case of new hire, it sometimes changes on daily basis as well. The challenge I am facing is that I am not able to pull historical reports as I don't know how the hierarchy was looking in past. I have Opportunities OWD set to private. For example:

Let's say I have two sales manager SM1 and SM2. SM1 had had 4 sales person (s1-s4) reporting him in Feb. Those 4 sales people had 2 sold deals (opportunity) each in Feb. SM2 had 2 sales person (S5,S6) reporting in feb who also sold 2 deals each. Now, let's say on March 1st my hierarchy changed and one salesperson S1 from SM1 is now reporting to SM2. So if I run the report now, SM2 gets credit for all the opportunity S1 sold in Feb when he was reporting to SM1.
I want a way when I ran the Feb report, SM1 can see the opportunity that S1 sold in Feb. But when I ran the report for March, SM2 should get visibility to only those opportunities that S1 sold when he was reporting to SM2 and not those which he sold under SM1. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify whether this problem is (a) with one specific report (b) with global functionality like Forecasting or (c) with record-level visibility? Different solutions may apply to different aspects of the problem.

Comment: Problem is with record level visibility. When one sales person moved under another manager, new manager gets visibility to all his records which sales person sold under previous manager.